# unable to connect to mysql through php on new page

Tags: php, mysql, access-denied

Super confused here. I've build a website that allows me to connect to mysql using php. I require common.php as you can see below, and have no issues connection, executing, etc.. to the database. What **does  not work** is when I use this exact same code on a new page that I'm developing. I can login with a test user to the site, but the page will not run any SQL queries to pull information from my database. The error I get is:

> "Access Denied for user 'ec2-user@localhost' (using password: NO)"

I do not understand why its trying to connect as ec2-user when thats obviously isn't what I'm asking the code to connect as.

Any help would be appreciated. I've been attempting to resolve this issue for a few days now and even with searching Father Google, I can't find a suitable answer.

Thanks!

**Common.php Code**

```
// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: index.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
}
```

**Code for common.php is below**

```
<?php 

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
$username = "username"; 
$password = "password"; 
$host = "myhostnotyours"; 
$dbname = "thedatabase"; 


$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try 
{ 

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 

    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

session_start();
```

Comment: In the error message it should also list a file and a line number. Try looking there.

Comment: in any other part of your code, you are using the ec2-user?

Comment: Where do you required common.php?

Comment: check the value of your password try $password= '';

Comment: Andre there is no place that I even have ec2-user in my code.

Comment: Andrewsi - in my header

Answer (score 0):

Probably the bit "(using password: NO)" is the bit you should be looking into. Do the password thing!

Then again why not narrow down the problem a bit - instead of posting 100+ lines of code

Answer (score 0):

set your password variable into null.

> $password = '';

Comment: When I set password to null I get this 

Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'StockDude'@'ip-172-31-20-178.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: NO)

Comment: And if I set the password to what the password is, it will load the page except for it won't run the query for a table and gives me the ec2-user@localhost access denied error.

Comment: did you check your config.inc in your folder file?

Comment: Hey Leonard, what I do a search for config.inc I am unable to find the file.

$ whereis config.inc
config: /usr/share/man/man5/config.5ssl.gz

Comment: what local server do you use? xampp? or wamp?

Comment: Its a LAMP setup that I have on an amazon AMI server.

Comment: Reinstalling the LAMP server? Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not going to do that.